# Squarespace Customized Two Column Navigation?

Tags: json, navigation, customization, squarespace

[image: Navigation now, and notes of what I want it to be I will use bootstrap for columns but within squarespace system I'm not quite sure how to access the right pieces of data. I'll get into that though]

Currently the  navigation is a single column. I would like to make it  capable of being 2 column and to  dynamically  fill  to  fit that way.

https://developers.squarespace.com/json-t-directives

I want to  know if  there is a  JSON-T Directive to get the current item being  printed in a loop like this:

```
{.repeated section items}
          {.collection?}
            {.even?}
            <a href="{collection.fullUrl}" class="Header-nav-folder-item{.if active} Header-nav-folder-item--active{.end}" data-test="template-nav">{collection.navigationTitle}</a>
           
          {.or}
            {.section externalLink}
              <a href="{url}"{.section newWindow} target="_blank"{.end} class="Header-nav-folder-item">{title}</a>
            {.end}
          {.end}
        {.end}
```

My  thought is  to  create 2  navigation  columns  based on the  number of  items in the  dropdown  navigation. I would  get the  number of  items in the  navigation by  using this variable  directive:

```
{.var @myLen items|count}
```

Then I would create another variable to  find the  halfway point where I  should  start navigation items to the other column:

```
{.var @halfLen @myLen/2}
```

I would  then  need to  know  what Item I am  iterating on (IE whether it is  element 1, 2, etc). I don't know if there is a directive for this though.

After that is known I would be able to  first end the  first  column then  start the second  column of this  navigation menu. This should allow me to make this idea work.

Is there a directive that will allow me to  make this  work or an alternate solution to making a 2 column layout without  hardcoding the header-nav.block file? Thank you.